# KaTeX font size

Tags: katex

The [function support](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/function-support.html#units) page of KaTeX states that the dimension of KaTeX units used for font dimensions are computed with respect to the surrounding HTML text. In particular, it states that

> G = 1.21 by default, because KaTeX font-size is normally 1.21 × the surrounding font size. This value can be over-ridden by the CSS of an HTML page. For example, on this page, G = 1.0.

Now the question is, where I should change the value of G?

Comment: Note that I don't want to override the method that KaTeX uses to compute the font dimension, I want to change the value of G.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the [KaTex wiki](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/wiki/Font-Options#font-size), that can be reset in CSS as, for example,

```
.katex { font-size: 1em !important; }
```

---

**Edit**

The documentation is no more hosted on the wiki of the project. You can see the same information in the new official documentation page [here](https://katex.org/docs/font.html).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Do you know why you need to write "!important" ? It only worked for me when I wrote that.

Comment: @Normajean it’s used to avoid that other selectors override the provide value, even if they have an higher specificity. So, it’s used when that value is really... important.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is now documented at: https://katex.org/docs/font.html

> By default, KaTeX math is rendered in a 1.21× larger font than the surrounding context, which makes super- and subscripts easier to read. You can control this using CSS, for example, to set to 1.1×:
>
> ```
> .katex { font-size: 1.1em; }
> ```

Doc source at: https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/blob/v0.10.2/docs/font.md

Comment: Do you know how to change the size of superscripts? I have a fraction, like 3^(1/2) but the 1 and the 2 are huge! they are the same size as the 3! I can make them smaller but then they are too far away from the divide line. I need the whole fraction smaller.

Comment: @Normajean nope! :-) Try creating an issue on their tracker, and link to it from here.